# Split Screen using HDMI Xubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, multiple-monitors, xubuntu, hdmi, tv

I've tried to get separate screens for Xubuntu 13.04 so I can browse on my laptop and use my TV to watch films via the HDMI port, but I'm unable to find a way to do it. What normally happens is I get full screen on the TV, but my laptop display gets warped showing 1/4 of the screen.

I've tried changing the resolution of my TV in *Monitor Settings*, but it just gets **HDMI No Signal** on the screen. I've tried arandr and grandr, but had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with xrandr, it has definitely more options, but you have to get into console... After you define your screens correctly, then they maybe start working correctly in arandr/grandr.